# Regex match if a couple options found but literally nothing else is

Tags: regex

How would I construct a regex that would match if either "foo" and "bar" (or any combination thereof) where present but NOTHING ELSE was?

So for example:

"**foo bar** ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit" - NO MATCH

"ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit **foo**" - NO MATCH

"**foo** ipsum dolor sit amet, **bar** consectetur adipiscing elit **foo**" - NO MATCH

"foo" - MATCH

"bar" - MATCH

"barfoo" - MATCH

"foobarbarfoofoobar" - MATCH

I'm trying to grok negative lookaheads but I haven't been able to crack this yet.

Comment: should "foo bar" or "bar, foo" match?

Comment: Is `foofoofoo` a valid match?

Comment: @DRC - First one yes, second one no.

Comment: @anubhava - yes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you need any combination of `foo` and `bar`, then something like this would be enough:

```
^(foo|bar)+$
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/n6R9D8/1)

It will capture `foo`, `bar`, `foobar`, `barfoofoo` and even `foobarbarfoofoobar`, etc.

**Edit:**

Since you also want to match `foo bar`, you'd have to include `\h`. Remember that `\h` matches spaces and tabs, while `\s` also matches new lines.

```
^((?:foo|bar)\h*)+$
```

[**Live preview**](https://regex101.com/r/n6R9D8/3)

Comment: @anubhava ohh forgot about that, fixed

Answer (score 1):

If you need to match also spaces characters you could use something like

```
^(foo|bar)+(foo|bar|\s)*$
```

this is a naive solution given ones showing capturing groups are already showed as answers.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this regex:

```
^\h*(?:(?:foo|bar)\h*)+$
```

[RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Zipw5q/4)